# Outlook email app not adding attachment

Tags: android, android-intent, outlook, start-activity, android-implicit-intent

Have written simple implicit intent for opening email application.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        emailIntent.setType("*/*");
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipientEmailID);

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody);
        if(attachment != null){
            ArrayList<Uri> attachmentList = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            attachmentList.add(attachment);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
        }
```

In Gmail app the attachement is showing. But, in Outlook it is not. I Googled a lot about and [github issue](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/issues/1336) . Can anyone please suggest what is the best option to show only email app for sharing with an attachement which works for at least top email apps.